# Creating list from Generator that pulls info from connected devices

Tags: python, grep

I successfully got a list to display but each item is on their own table. I'm then trying to run an input check on the generated table, but it's only comparing the last item from the results. I'm mixing some `grep` functions with subprocess.

The structure goes a bit like this.

```
devices_connected = subprocess.getoutput(grep function to grab number of usb devices connected)

def device_list():
    for i in range(1, devices_connected +1)
        info_1 = subprocess.getoutput(grep 1) #with sliced info get get a certian ouput
        info_2 = subprocess.getoutput(grep 2 etc)
        info_3 = subprocess.getoutput(grep 3 etc)

        output ="".join("{}|{}|{}".format(info_1, info_2, info3))

        yield output

for result in device_list():
    info_1, info_2, info_3 = result.split("|")
    list1 = info_1.split()
    list2 = info_2.split()
    list3 = info_3.split()
    print(f"{info_1} | {info_2} | {info_3}") #this prints the info properly as intended

    print(list1)
       output: 
          ['item1'] 
          ['item2'] 
          ['item3']
    # Without the split, it would print the same but without the quotes or brackets
```

and when I print outside of the for statement, I only get `['item3']`

```
print(list1)
    output: ['item3']
```

The output I'm going for is

```
    list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

I've tried to list them together before and after splitting. Even tried combining the output into a list in the `device_list()` function.

Comment: You need to indent the 3 lines under the first `for i`

Comment: Thanks for the callout on the typo, edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Apologies, duly noted. I'll be sure to add the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to get a list from the generator to run against. For each generated item, I put them into their own function. And was able to call the info successfuly to run an input to compare it against to make sure the line broke if an answer that wasn't on the list was submitted.

```
def fucntion1():
    for i in range(1, devices_connected +1)
        info_1 = subprocess.getoutput(grep function to grab USB info_1)
        yield info_1
```

Then was able to call the generated items, that change depending on what's connected, into a list outside of the function successfully.

```
function1_list = function()
print(list(function1_list)
```

output ends up being what I was intending to get.

> ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'etc']

done this three times for each grep command, yielding the results I wanted in a list, and was able to move forward successfully.